# How do I open the program files folder for the application I just installed?

Tags: c#, installation

Creating a C# install package and I'd like on completed install for the "Program Files/My Application" folder to open.

Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the following:                 public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);

            string strDir = "C:\\Program Files\\My Application";

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", strDir);
        }
But no matter what I put in there for the path, I get an error like "MyApplication\InstallActions.InstallState cannot be found :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, where do I put this? As a post-build event?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a custom action. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28VS.80%29.aspx) is an example that opens a web page after install.

Instead of opening the webpage, just use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get the location and open the directory by starting an explorer process with the path args.